# Centos 6.7 Emulex LPE12002 on Dell can't see any targets/LUNS on HP EVA4400 SAN

Tags: hp, storage-area-network, dell-poweredge, fibre-channel, emulex

As the title indicates -- I have a new Dell R730xd running Centos 6.7 with all updates loaded, etc.  I also installed the Emulex utilities, etc.

The issue is that nothing I try (reboot / rescan-scsi-bus.sh / manually) is making any of the LUNS appear to the OS.  I am not seeing anything in
/dev/disk/by-path  for anything but the 2 native SCSI drives.

The output of the hbacmd listhbas comes back ok.

I am getting these messages in the kernel -- but google research showed they are "harmless" (famous last words) .. the various UP and Downs are from doing the rescans (or so it appears)...

```
Nov 10 15:57:51 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1303 Link Up Event x3 received Data: x3 x1 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 15:57:51 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:3334 Delay fc port discovery for 10 seconds
Nov 10 15:58:21 lxsc175 kernel: rport-1:0-0: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 15:58:27 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:(0):6789 rport name 200200051e0cd23f != node port name 200300051e0cd23f
Nov 10 15:58:27 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:1305 Link Down Event x2 received Data: x2 x20 x110 x0 x0
Nov 10 15:58:30 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:1303 Link Up Event x3 received Data: x3 x0 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 15:58:30 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:3334 Delay fc port discovery for 10 seconds
Nov 10 15:58:32 lxsc175 kernel: rport-1:0-4: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 15:59:00 lxsc175 kernel: rport-2:0-0: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 15:59:11 lxsc175 kernel: rport-2:0-4: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 16:04:50 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:(0):3050 lpfc_board_mode set to offline
Nov 10 16:04:51 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:(0):3050 lpfc_board_mode set to online
Nov 10 16:04:53 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1303 Link Up Event x1 received Data: x1 xf7 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 16:04:57 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:(0):3050 lpfc_board_mode set to offline
Nov 10 16:04:58 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:(0):3050 lpfc_board_mode set to online
Nov 10 16:04:59 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:1303 Link Up Event x1 received Data: x1 xf7 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 16:05:24 lxsc175 kernel: rport-1:0-6: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 16:05:30 lxsc175 kernel: rport-2:0-6: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 16:08:56 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1305 Link Down Event x2 received Data: x2 x20 x110 x0 x0
Nov 10 16:08:57 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1303 Link Up Event x3 received Data: x3 x0 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 16:09:19 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1305 Link Down Event x4 received Data: x4 x20 x110 x0 x0
Nov 10 16:09:19 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.0: 0:1303 Link Up Event x5 received Data: x5 x0 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 16:09:49 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:1305 Link Down Event x2 received Data: x2 x20 x110 x0 x0
Nov 10 16:09:49 lxsc175 kernel: lpfc 0000:03:00.1: 1:1303 Link Up Event x3 received Data: x3 x0 x20 x0 x0 x0 0
Nov 10 16:09:50 lxsc175 kernel: rport-1:0-7: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
Nov 10 16:10:20 lxsc175 kernel: rport-2:0-7: blocked FC remote port time out: removing rport
```

Upfront -- I am a SAN newbie -- but I've read a lot of doc on how to do it -- but the basic just seeing the LUNs is throwing me for a loop!

I just installed the latest Emulex Linux driver 10.6.144.21 but that didn't resolve or change anything.

Thanks in advance!

/Steve

Comment: Can you confirm that the FC switeches zoning is ok ? Otherwise the HBAs won't be able to reach the SAN array

Comment: I'll double check with the SAN guys -- but they indicated it was done properly.  The status of the fc_host also appeared to say (I don't remember exactly which thing I checked)  that it was connected to a Fabric and had a speed, etc. and some traffic was being transmitted.  So at least the physical connection to the FC Switch seemed to be ok.

Comment: What you describe is basically that the HBA logs into the FC Fabric. My question was about zoning, i.e. does a zone exist to allows the HBA to access the SAN array (EVA controllers) ?

Comment: Solved!  The SAN guys by-passed the FC Fabric switch (which I guess was having some odd problems anyway) - -and viola -- everything came up just fine and the LUNS appeared, etc. Everything is happy.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The SAN guys by-passed the FC Fabric switch (which I guess was having some odd problems anyway) - -and viola -- everything came up just fine and the LUNS appeared, etc. Everything is happy.

So, at some point we'll have to figure out what's wrong with the FC Brocade thing, but that's a problem for a different day.